# C: запись значений в переменные по ссылке "не работает"

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Вот код:

```
void func_Add(double *result)
{
    double arg1 = 0;
    double arg2 = 0;

    prepearData(&arg1, &arg2);
    printf("\nEntered arguments: %lf and %lf\n", arg1, arg2);
    *result = arg1 + arg2;
    printf(">>Addition result: %lf \n", *result);
}
```

в функцию prepearData передаются параметры arg1 и arg2.

```
void prepearData(double *arg1, double *arg2)
{
        printf(">> Enter FIRST argument:");
        scanf("%lf", &arg1);
        printf(">> Enter SECOND argument:");
        scanf("%lf", &arg2);
        printf("\prepearData: %lf and %lf\n", arg1, arg2);
}
```

Проблема в том, что в *arg1 и в *arg1 значения не записываются.
Если объявить в этой функции переменные и считать в них, то данные считаются.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этой функции записать в переменные arg1 и arg2 значения?

Спасибо

Comment: Вас компилятор не предупредил об ошибках в `scanf` и `printf`?

Comment: Я использую VS 2017, нет, не предупредил

Comment: Хм... Вроде бы именно в 2017 это стало предупреждением компилятора, а не свойством анализатора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы *уже* выделили место для записи считываемых значений и передали в функцию соответствующие адреса - так что вам

1. нужно просто передавать эти адреса в `scanf`
2. нужно разыменовывать эти адреса в `printf`

Вот так:

```
void prepearData(double *arg1, double *arg2)
{
        printf(">> Enter FIRST argument:");
        scanf("%lf", arg1);
        printf(">> Enter SECOND argument:");
        scanf("%lf", arg2);
        printf("\prepearData: %lf and %lf\n", *arg1, *arg2);
}
```

То, что вы пытались делать - это записывать данные в локальные переменные `arg1` и `arg2`, для этого не приспособленные - хотя бы потому, что они являются указателями...

Добавлю, что это - не передача по ссылке (таковая имеется в С++, но не в С), а обычная передача указателя по значению (которую иногда (на мой взгляд, совершенно ошибочно) именуют передачей по указателю).

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

У вас ошибка в вызовах `scanf` и `printf`. Дело в том, что `arg1` и `arg2` это уже адреса. В вашем варианте вы перезаписываете указатели, а не сами переменные. Уберите лишние амперсенды и все должно заработать:

```
scanf("%lf", arg1);
. . .
printf("\prepearData: %lf and %lf\n", *arg1, *arg2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!